# multitail - custom config (multitail.conf) location

Tags: configuration, tail, multitail

Is it possible to provide a custom location for `multitail.conf`, or are my only options `/etc/multiltail.conf` or `~/multitail.conf`?

I'd like to provide a specific config file that has regexes specific to our app defined, but I can't put this in the account's home directory, or `/etc`.

I care most about the colors, so if it's possible to reference those from a separate file, then that would work well too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can tell `multitail` where to source the configuration file from by using the `--config` switch.

```
   --config filename
          Load the configuration from given filename.
```

See the man page for more info.

Answer (score 1):

This might depend on which version of MultiTail you have.

This is for **v6.4.2** (via `$ multitail -V`).

Run

```
$ multitail -h          #and it says the following:

*** configuration file ***  
-F file                  use 'file' as configuration file (instead of /etc/multitail.conf)  
--no-load-global-config  do not read /etc/multitail.conf  
-o config_file_parameter do a setting which would normally be set in the configuration file
```

This conflicts with what the man page says, in that the man page lists both -F and --config.

BTW there are other apparent errors in the man page, or at least it doesn't match what `$multitail -h` says.

So go figure.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

just simple like that:

```
alias multitail='multitail -F customconfiglocation'
```